# Include spaces in commands called from json

Tags: json, windows, cmd, escaping

I'm trying to run the following command:

`C:/Users/Annoying Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python C:/Users/Annoying Username/Desktop/MyApp.py`

Which returns the following error: `C:/Users/Annoying` is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program, or batch file`. Clearly the space char is the issue. I realize that quotes fix this, but the problem in this instance is that I'm actually trying to run this from a json file (as the "sideCommand" in [ampm](https://github.com/stimulant/ampm):

`"sideCommand" : "C:/Users/Annoying Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python C:/Users/Annoying Username/Desktop/MyApp.py"`

So the whole command needs to be wrapped in quotes. How can I get the space character in the username to pass as part of the command within the json string?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the QUOTATION MARK characters as escaped? `"\"C:/Users/.../Python36/python\" \"C:/Users...` https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output

Comment: Aha, no I haven't. I may try that the next chance I get maybe tomorrow, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I actually got around this problem using this method to change the Annoying Username to something without a space in it: https://superuser.com/a/986487/892036